# Warning CS0618 in "Microsoft.Graph" Version="5.36.0"

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

When I use the line:

```
GrantResponse? respons = await graphClient.Shares[driveItem.Id].Permission.Grant.PostAsync(requestBody);
```

I get the following warning:

```
Warning CS0618  'GrantResponse' is obsolete: 'This class is obsolete. Use grantPostResponse instead.'   
Warning CS0618  'GrantResponse' is obsolete: 'This class is obsolete. Use grantPostResponse instead.'   
Warning CS0618  'GrantRequestBuilder.PostAsync(GrantPostRequestBody, Action<RequestConfiguration<DefaultQueryParameters>>?, CancellationToken)' is obsolete: 'This method is obsolete. Use PostAsGrantPostResponse instead.'
```

I am Using "Microsoft.Graph" Version="5.36.0"

I looked in the Graph SDK documentations and no mention of these and no good example how to add a simple write permission to a DriveItem
Anyone knows a good documentation source?

Comment: Did you try reading the messages and doing what they say?

Comment: What they say is "Use grantPostResponse instead" and "Use PostAsGrantPostResponse instead" but there is no documentations for "grantPostResponse" or "PostAsGrantPostResponse". Do you know where the documentation for that is?

Comment: @OferGal You don't need any documentation for that; just change your code from `GrantResponse? respons` to `GrantPostResponse? respons` - and change `Permission.Grant.PostAsync(requestBody)`  to `Permission.Grant.PostAsGrantPostResponse` - and then tell us what happens (does it compile? do you get a different error? etc)

Comment: The code:
```
 var result = await graphClient.Drives[driveItem.ParentReference.DriveId].Items[driveItem.Id].Invite.PostAsInvitePostResponseAsync(grantRequestBody);                       
```
Compiles and runs. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I've checked the source code of the SDK and the method `PostAsGrantPostResponseAsync` was introduced in version 5.29, but there is nothing in [the release notes](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/releases/tag/5.29.0). Yes, the correct name is `PostAsGrantPostResponseAsync` not `PostAsGrantPostResponse` as mentioned in the warning.

I guess that they decided to change the naming of some methods, but they want to give some time to developers to rewrite their code.

What's important, both methods `PostAsync` and `PostAsGrantPostResponseAsync` call [the same endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/permission-grant?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp). Yes, the example for C# in the doc is using obsolete method.

Simply replace `PostAsync` with `PostAsGrantPostResponseAsync` and change the type of the result from `GrantResponse` to `GrantPostResponse`.

```
GrantPostResponse? response = await graphClient.Shares[driveItem.Id].Permission.Grant.PostAsGrantPostResponseAsync(requestBody);
```

Comment: ```var response = await graphClient.Shares[driveItem.Id].Permission.Grant.PostAsGrantPostResponseAsync(grantRequestBody) ``` compiled fine (GrantPostResponse?  was not found ) .
but at run time there was an error  "The provided share id was malformed."

Comment: ```var response = await graphClient.Shares[driveItem.Id].Permission.Grant.PostAsGrantPostResponseAsync(grantRequestBody) ``` compiled fine (GrantPostResponse?  was not found ) .
but at run time there was an error  "The provided share id was malformed."
I used the DriveItem from 
```DriveItem driveItem = await graphClient.Sites[projectSite.Id].Lists["DPC Documents"].Items[item.Id].DriveItem.GetAsync();``` 
Pre 5.xx The code :```await graphClient.Sites[projectSite.Id].Lists["DPC Documents"].Items[item.Id].DriveItem.Invite(recipients, requireSignIn, roles).Request().PostAsync();```  why

Comment: @OferGal You are passing driveItem.Id, but the endpoint requires some [shared url](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/permission-grant?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#encoding-sharing-urls). If you used [send an invite](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-invite?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) endpoint then you need to use another c# [code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-invite?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#http-request-1). Maybe create a new question if you will need help with sending an invite